# Bi conditional Statements:Did the author make a mistake in the passage?

Tags: propositional-calculus

The book I am reading called *How to prove it* mentions the following, which I think it might be wrong but not sure.

> One of the reasons it's so easy to confuse a conditional statement
>   with its converse is that in everday speech we sometimes use a
>   conditional statement when we mean to convey is actually a
>   bi-conditional statement... Suppose a child is told by his parents,
>   "if you don't eat your dinner, you won't get any dessert." The child
>   certainly expects that if he does eat his dinner, he will get dessert,
>   although that's not literally what his parents said. In other words,
>   the child interprets the statement as meaning "Eating your dinner is a
>   necessary and sufficient condition for getting dessert."

Do you think the example he gave was a good example? I do not think so because it does not sound like we assume a biconditional statement in everyday language. It's more like we mean (P-->Q)V(~P-->~Q)(**Edit:** it should be (P-->Q)/\(~P-->~Q) since (P-->Q)V(~P-->~Q) is a tautology) in everyday speech, instead the biconditional (P-->Q)/\ (Q-->P) which the author says.Maybe I am getting this wrong or do not understand it well or he gave a bad example. Please help make this clear for me, thanks.

Comment: I do not believe your version captures the intended meaning. For one thing, if $P$ is eat dinner and $Q$ is have dessert, then your statement is true if one always gets dessert.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I did a truth table for (P-->Q)V(~P-->~Q) and P<-->Q. It looks (P-->Q)V(~P-->~Q) is a tautology. It doesn't look equivalent to P<-->Q. Maybe I made a mistake in the truth table , but I'll double check.

Comment: Yeah, I read $\lor$ as $\land$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example does illustrate the author’s point; it’s very similar to examples that I’ve used in my classes to make the same point. Let $P$ be *you do not eat your dinner*, and let $Q$ be *you will not get any dessert*. The original statement then appears to be $P\to Q$. However, as the author points out, the child understands the statement to mean not only $P\to Q$, but also $\neg P\to\neg Q$: *if you do eat your dinner, you will get dessert*. In other words, the child understands the original English statement to mean $(P\to Q)\land(\neg P\to\neg Q)$ (and that’s undoubtedly what the parent meant).

Now $\neg P\to\neg Q$ is logically equivalent to $Q\to P$, as you can check by examining its truth table. (It’s called the *contrapositive* of $Q\to P$.) Thus, $(P\to Q)\land(\neg P\to\neg Q)$ is logically equivalent to $(P\to Q)\land(Q\to P)$, which in turn is logically equivalent to the biconditional $P\leftrightarrow Q$.

In other words, the author is correct: in that context we understand the statement *if you don’t eat your dinner, you won’t get any dessert* as

> *if you don’t your dinner, you won’t get any dessert; and if you do eat your dinner, you will get some dessert*,

which is logically equivalent to the biconditional

> *if you don’t your dinner, you won’t get any dessert; and if dont’ get any dessert, you didn’t eat your dinner*.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the following statements are equivalent (in classical logic).

1. $(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow P)$
2. $(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q)$

To see this, note that, by the law of contraposition (applied twice), we have

$$(P \rightarrow Q) \implies (\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P) \implies (\neg\neg P \rightarrow \neg\neg Q).$$

However, by double negation elimination, the expression on the right is logically equivalent to the one on the left. Thus

$$(P \rightarrow Q) \iff (\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P),$$

from which the equivalence of interest follows.